# Add Shortcode tag in Widget/Sidebar

Tags: plugins, widgets, shortcode

I want to add a shortcode tag in the sidebar/widget.

I am able to get the required functionality if I add the code in the theme's function.php

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

My problem is that I am searching for a way I can do this from the plugins files itself without affecting any of the theme files.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Comment: Add the line to your child themes functions file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Do shortcode in side-widget
Description: Let's do it.
Version: 0.1
Author: CyberPanda
*/

add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty easy. Just create a plugin
http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Standard_Plugin_Information

and put your function code there. The only risk is that it can be accidentally deactivated by users with relevant privelages.

Comment: I have created a plugin. How do I add this code in the plugin is my question.

Comment: @molokom Please explain how much you can instead of providing external links :)

Comment: @sri ok. I thought link to the codex were ok. I'll do better next time.